# jquery - autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I m using autocomplete from

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

i managed to get data from server in below form but in autocomplete list i dont see spaces that i added after **supplier** , i even tried removing trim all over from the script but that does not solved my issue.Please suggest.

Exon:      Supplier          HJR/VAKJ -1

Comment: You need to post some code, preferably enough that we can reproduce this.  Remove all the other code and have only the autocomplete with a hard coded list.  From there start adding back code until it breaks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery autocomplete - how to massage the options before displaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042722/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-massage-the-options-before-displaying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a jQuery or Autocomplete issue. It's how HTML works: Whitespace in the source code is irrelevant by design.

To enforce spaces that also appear on the screen, use ["non-breaking spaces"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space): Reference them either by their HTML entity name `&nbsp;`, by their numbered entity `&#160;` or by replacing space characters by `Chr(160)` directly. It depends on your server side software how to do it, but it is reasonably simple.

So this:

```
Exon:    Supplier    HJR/VAKJ -1
```

would become, for example:

```
Exon:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Supplier&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HJR/VAKJ -1
```

Be sure to use a fixed-width font for presentation, or you will see jagged columns on the screen.