# Jquery autocomplete - how to massage the options before displaying?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I m using autocomplete from

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1

i managed to get data from server in below form with sepaerator to id as "-", but i dont want to show this id in list while selecting but sending it as hidden data.Please suggest.

Exon: Supplier HJR/VAKJ -1

Answer (score 0):

try `formatItem: function(){ ... }`

```
$("...").autocomplete(data, {
 //.....
     formatItem: function(item) {
        return item.text.substr(0,item.text.lastIndexOf('-'));
     }
 //.....    
})
```

more on [it here.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply buddy, but  i tried it and it is saying item.text is undefined..

Comment: well, never tried that really but I guess, you can check the codes example here... http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/ just view the page source...